# What is the different between set a UITableView cell height with setRowHeight function and tableView: heightForRowAtIndexPath: function?

Tags: ios

Just like the title, what's the different between this two method?

I find that if I set its height with tableView: heightForRowAtIndexPath:, and then I want to get the value of height, I will get a right value by this:

```
CGFloat height = cell.frame.size.height;
```

but a wrong value by this, the result is 44:

```
CGFloat height = tableview.rowHeight;
```

But if I set it in the other way -- setRowHeight:, I can get right value in both the two way.

So what's the different between them?

Answer (score 5):

`rowHeight` is a property on `UITableView` and is used for setting the table row height when the delegate does not implement `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

From [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW30),

> You may set the row height for cells if the delegate doesn't implement the tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: method. If you do not explicitly set the row height, UITableView sets it to a standard value.

When row height is returned from delegate method `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` the value of property `rowHeight` is set to default (IMO, 44 points).

Apple recommends `rowHeight` in special use cases,

> There are performance implications to using tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: instead of rowHeight. Every time a table view is displayed, it calls tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: on the delegate for each of its rows, which can result in a significant performance problem with table views having a large number of rows (approximately 1000 or more).

In my experience `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` is used when cell height is dynamic. For example, you have to display multiline text of varying height in each cell. In such cases, calculate and return the dynamic height of the cell using this delegate method.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you! But why I can't get the correct height of cell with table.rowHieght, if I set it with delegate? All cells has the same height.

Comment: @pingshw `UITableView` assumes that a cell might have dynamic height when it is returned from delegate method. While `table.rowHeight` will assume that all cells have same height (static). Hence you will get incorrect  value from `table.rowHeight` when you implement delegate method.